# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine after new Eclipse Install

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just switched my boot drive to a new drive and am still using my old C drive for storage. I tried to run Eclipse from the old C drive and it told me that its "executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library". I then went ahead and reinstalled the same version of Eclipse (2020.3) and tried to run it, where I got this new error. I have tried some solutions people have used in the past but none of them seem to work for my issue.

If I had to take a stab, Eclipse is referencing a file that my old install used which is no longer valid, but I honestly have no clue. When I try to launch, I get a Java Virtual Machine Launcher popup with the error in the title. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Exit Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVdTd.png)

Comment: You have a 32 bit Java, but 64 bit is required. Get the current Eclipse version with the right embedded Java instead.

Comment: `I have tried some solutions people have used in the past but none of them seem to work for my issue.` Don't ever say stuff like that. We have no idea what you did or did not do. You need to enumerate what you have tried so that we don't waste time suggesting things that  you've already tried. Your problem can have numerous causes, but neither I nor other people want to take random shots in the dark when you could just include the pertinent details. Remember that you're asking strangers to help you for free, which means you need to make helping as easy as possible.

Comment: @howlger Thank you for the advice, I went ahead and followed your instructions and Eclipse launched fine.